# Parking brake needs constant maintenance

Tags: jeep, parking-brake, liberty

Every other year my parking brake fails inspection.  The problem is almost always the parking brake levers and actuators have froze.  Typically, I take it apart, clean off any brake dust and rust, add a little antiseize lubricant (Permatex Aluminum), and reinstall.  This buys me a year or two before it seizes again.  The vehicle gets driven a few times a month but it sits outside.  I can hammer on it from the outside and get a few days out of it, but I really hate taking this apart all the time to repair it, it's time consuming especially with the disc/drum combo.  I could replace it, but I'm not sure it would be any different.  What advice do you have for solving this (for more than a few years anyway)?  Keep in mind I live in a snow belt where they use lots of salt on the roads.

[image: Parking Brake Lever]

Comment: Do you use the brake?

Comment: @GdD yes, its a standard.

Comment: As an off the cuff suggestion, I'd consider using a different lubricant.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I typically use Permatex Aluminum

Comment: I would focus on trying to keep salt and water out of the drum.

Comment: @GdD The actuator is 1/2 out of the drum through a rubber flap, but its not a perfect seal and won't be with how it's designed.  The problem is the other end of the actuator, the seal would have to be very tight to prevent water from travelling across it.

Comment: Where does this part attach to the vehicle?

Comment: @D.SM Inside the drum (presses the shoes out when pulled), connects to the actuator, which goes through a little rubber slit connecting to the parking brake cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anti-seize isn't actually the product you are looking for, it's designed to keep threads from seizing, not to lubricate parts that are moving often. What you want is an actual brake lubricant that will stay on the parts and not get rubbed off or dry out. There are a load of fully synthetic specialist brake greases, I'd recommend one of those, or a marine grease.

Comment: I ended up ordering replacements that are coated to prevent rust, combined with using a lubricant instead of anti-seize hopefully will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already provided answer to use grease instead of anti-seize:

- If the car has a manual transmission, do not pull the parking brake up as hard as you can. Pull it up lightly and leave the car in gear.
- Periodically walk up to the vehicle when it's parked and move the parking brake handle through its full range of motion a few times to re-lubricate the lever.

You may consider looking for thicker/heavier chassis grease that is meant to *remain* on ball joints and such instead of bearing grease that is meant to be *contained* in the bearing by seals. Hopefully the brake grease is more like chassis  grease in this regard.